# Overriding local modules from community pool

Tags: overrides

I have an extension in the local pool. I would need to override the Block in the module. Can I do it from the community pool.

(yes, I know this is not how it should be done, but I'm making a small fix to an existing system)

Answer (score 3):

If by "override" you mean copy the class in the "community" folder, it won't work.
The sequence of folders the autoloader checks is this:

- `app/code/local`
- `app/code/community`
- `app/code/core`
- `lib`

If by "override" you mean an actual override, by declaring a different class for a specific block in your `config.xml` it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can rewrite everything from everywhere.

Magento doesn't matter where the rewrite comes from, as long as it is there.